# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^{w-1}{2^i} = 2^w - 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

The title says it all, I guess. Why
$$\sum_{i=0}^{w-1}{2^i} = 2^w - 1$$

Comment: Call the sum $S(w)$.  Can you relate $S(w)$ to $2S(w)$ in some helpful way?

Comment: Do you recognize how/why $999999+1 = 1000000$?  If we were in binary instead, why $111111_2+1_2=1000000_2$?  As for a proof, have you ever heard of a proof by induction?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show it is true for some special value of w? Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: Yea I know that I could prove it by induction but isn't there some algebraic reasoning for the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to look at it.  $$\begin{align}S=1+&2+4+8+\cdots+2^n\\
2S=\ \ &2+4+8+\cdots+2^n+2^{n+1}\end{align}$$ Subtract the first equation from the second to get $S=2^{n+1}-1$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive way to see it:

Say you want to compute $$1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4\tag{1}$$ If you add $1$ to the sum $(1)$ you'll get: $$(1+1)+2+2^2+2^3+2^4\\=(2+2)+2^2+2^3+2^4\\=(2^2+2^2)+2^3+2^4\\=(2^3+2^3)+2^4\\=(2^4+2^4)\\=2^5$$

Since we added $1$, the sum is $1$ less, that is, $$2^5-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Say we set 
$$s_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k.$$
We see that 
$$s_{n+1}(x)=x^n+s_n(x).$$
But we also see that 
$$xs_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k=s_{n+1}(x)-1.$$
Hence we have
$$xs_n(x)=s_n(x)+x^n-1,$$
which means that for $x\ne 1$,
$$s_n(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.$$
The sum in question is given by 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{w-1}2^i=s_{w}(2)=\frac{2^w-1}{2-1}=2^w-1.$$